# How to replace a value within a large string in R

Tags: r

I have a long string (comes from a SQL query) that contains this phrase:

"AND RO.[TPID] = 18411436"

I want to replace the number portion each time I go through a loop. How do I exctract the pattern so I can perform a sub or str_replace?

When I run grep("[TPID] = ",x) it returns a 0 as it didn't find that pattern.
The length of the number also varies is it is not always 8 digits and I don't know the number so I can't just do a search for the number.

Thanks!

Comment: Add `fixed = TRUE` to your `grep` call and it should find it.

Comment: You can try `gsub('= [0-9]+', paste0('= ', 'replacement_string'), s)` where `s` is the string. You can feed it a vector too from a data frame you have.

Comment: Yes, the fixed = TRUE found the instance, but I was unable to use any regular expression so I could find the entire string fragment, such as suggested in [0-9]+ or [:digits:]+. If I type in the number verbatim I can make the substitution so I need the right expression to capture the varying number.